# Report Manager user interface customization: change the logo

Tags: reporting-services

I want to customize report manager logo so it displays our company logo. I have changed "ReportingServices.css" and "RSWebParts.css". Also, I changed "48folderopen.jpg" with our company logo, and I renamed the logo to "48folderopen.jpg".

However, none of these changed anything. What (else) needs to be done to change the logo?

Comment: What version of SQL Server is installed?

Comment: @MikeHoney I have done it, thnx